# How to remove special characters in String

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove `"[", "]"`, `","` from my string
for example,

```
[569.24, 569.24, 568.10, 566.00, 566.01, 566.00, 567.98, 565.14]
```

to

```
569.24 569.24 568.10 566.00 566.01 566.00 567.98 565.14
```

however, I can remove `","` but `"["` and `"]"`

my codes are as follows.

```
String content = price_result.toString();           
//remove special characters
String content_modified = content.replaceAll("[ \t\"',;]+", " ");
System.out.println(content_modified);
```

the above result in `[569.24, 569.24, 568.10, 566.00, 566.01, 566.00, 567.98, 565.14]`..

How can I remove `"["` and `"]"`?

Comment: this looks like an XY problem. is `price_result.toString()` returning an array `Arrays.toString` output?

Comment: I agree with @Reimeus, or more likely a `List<String>`

Comment: `replaceAll` takes regex as first parameter and `[` and `]` creates character class in regex `[...]` so they are metacharacters. But I agree with Reimeus, it looks like your problem is not in code you showed but in way you produce your output.

Comment: Poster, as @Reimeus is intimating in his [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) comment, you may be barking up the wrong tree. For a better and more robust answer tell us how you generate this String in the first place. A less "kludgy" solution is to generate a better String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this

```
String content = price_result.toString();           
//remove special characters
String content_modified = content.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","");
System.out.println(content_modified);
```

Comment: This is horrible. What if there are other brackets in the `String`? Don't do this.

Comment: than they will also be removed, as he asked

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next:

```
// Characters you want to remove
String unwanted = "[],";

// It will be used frequently? Use a constant.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + Pattern.quote(unwanted) + "]");

String content = price_result.toString();
String content_modified = pattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
System.out.println(content_modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in character class `[]` with escape character `\`

```
String content_modified = content.replaceAll("[\\[\t\"',;\\]]+", " ");
```

Or pipe them one by one(put other characters yourself :)

```
String content_modified = content.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|;", " ");
```